# TextAlignment="Right" has no effect in WPF XAML bound to int field?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, int

The binding works great, but as soon as I bind to to an field of type int,
the field no longer gets alignet to the right?

```
<TextBlock 
 TextAlignment="Right"
 Width="50"
 Text="{Binding SomeIntField}">
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: could you give as an example of the XAML(including its parents layouts)

What is your width set to? Auto or a constant?

Comment: the code was in there, seems to be auto removed?

<TextBlock 
 TextAlignment="Right"
 Width="50"
 Text="{Binding SomeIntField}">
</TextBlock>

Comment: the parent is a <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
containing some more textblocks.

Comment: @wpf.Binding: You should better edit your post, and copy the code in there. Furthermore, you should provide the surrounding code because it might be related to that. And third, you should tell us *how* it is aligned if it is no longer right-aligned. Is it left-aligned? Centered? Hidden completely? ...

Comment: I tried, but the code is removed.
it is left-aligned.

the surrounding code is horizontal stackpanel

Comment: <TextBlock
 TextAlignment="Right"
 Width="50"
 Text="{Binding SomeIntField}">
</TextBlock>

Comment: I edited the code to make it visible. Either highlight the code block and select the "101010" icon or add 4 spaces at the beginning of each line. You *will* have to supply more code than this though.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you replace the Binding with a hard-coded value? E.g. instead of `Text="{Binding SomeIntField}"` use `Text="10"`. This is no solution, but it might help in finding one.

Answer (score 0):

yes, as soon as I use test="10" it gets right-aligned correctly.
thats why I suppose it has to be something with the field type int?

what other code is needed? I thought this would be the minmal code to reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem in Blend. You do not have the `Width` set to `Auto`, do you?! It really is fixed to 50?! And you really set the `TextAlignment` property, not the `HorizontalAlignment` property?! If so, please post additional code: the XAML around this TextBlock (the StackPanel), maybe other XAML as well. Plus the code of the property you are binding to. Otherwise, noone will be able to help you because the code that you posted is absolutely valid and makes the text right-aligned, no matter what the `Text` property is bound to.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBlock element starts unbinded, so the width isnt set, after the binding the width isnt scaled proper. You can bind the width of the TextBlock with the width of the parent to solve this problem.